# How do I find all subdirectories (any number of levels) named "x" using windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, glob

I have something like this...

```
patch-1
    html
        test.html
patch-2
    patch-2-a
        html
            test.html
            test2.html

    patch-2-b
        html
            test3.html
...
```

I want to search all the main folders and subfolders for any folders named html. Then I want to take these files and copy and replace them into `c:\html`. I would like to do all of this using a batch file.

In the glob world I could do this like...

```
.\**\html
```

But not sure how to do this in Windows shell

How would I loop through all subfolders (no matter how many levels deep) and recursively copy anything into it into c:\html?

Comment: `for /?` and `dir /?`. To list all folders containing html `dir /b /s c:\*html*`

Comment: If you want to only find **folders** named `html`, then I would tweak the command @CatCat provided and use `dir /ad /b /s html`.

Comment: `dir /B /S /A:D "D:\main\html"` works, but only if `D:\main` does not contain a sub-directory `html` on its own (if it does, its content is listed). If this could happen, you could do `for /R "D:\main" %%D in (html) do if exist "%%D\" echo %%D`

Comment: Put an asterisk in front of html. `dir /B /S /A:D "D:\main\*html"`

Comment: @CatCat, this would also return `somehtml`, for example, so you'd need some post-filtering...